# Detect darker or lighter background colors using jQuery or PHP

Tags: php, jquery, colors

This one is bit tough. I made a style switcher for website demo that changes specific div background color. Everything works fine but since that div also contains text and headings , if visitors changes the background to white the headings and text are gone.

So instead adding switch for headings or text for that container , id rather detect the background color change and this way affect the text inside.

By using Tyny color jQuery plugin I set the colors of headings and paragraph to 30% lighter and works almost ok but once you get to white or any way near white I need it to switch to dark.

Is there any way to detect darker/lighter color codes by using jQuery TinyColor and Colorpicker plugin or php? Reason why I also ask for php is because I ported that demo to php as well so either one would work for me.

I have setup a small demo here for you to test 
http://jsfiddle.net/mwVz6/12/

code is pretty simple and for the demo and my switcher I am using color picker from 
http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000ff',
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#container').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    }
});
```

Comment: And here is the full jquery/php version just in case anyone else needs it http://themergency.com/calculate-text-color-based-on-background-color-brightness/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could this be of any use to you?

> https://github.com/joggink/jquery-colorcontrast
>
> http://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast/

Your best bet might be to develop a function which calculates a delta (difference) on how close 2 specific colors are to each other. If the delta is below a certain threshold, you increase the text color to this threshold. The challenge is to determine if the color should be darker or lighter.